# Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers tooltip color

Tags: java, eclipse, tooltip

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers version 4.5.0 (Mars).
But the tooltip background is black. How can I change it??
I am using xubuntu 14.04

P.S.
The tooltip background at the system level is white, using gnome color chooser.
And I set The Java doc view background at (general -> appearance -> colors and fonts) to white
And also none of the Appearance color options at (Java -> editor) are black!
Is it a bug in the new version of eclipse??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same problem.

I assume this is because Eclipse 4.5 uses GTK3 by default (gtkrc-2.0 settings will not be used).

So you can:

- edit tooltip colors in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/setting.ini + gtk-main.css
- or [force Eclipse to use GTK2](https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-eclipse-on-gtk2-or-on-gtk3/)

I prefer the second choice.

Add

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

in /etc/profile and restart the system

Comment: Or start Eclipse from a shell script and add `export SWT_GTK3=0` there.  This answer saved my week, BTW.

Comment: The `export SWT_GTK=0` trick did not work for me, however editing the tooltip colors did (Ubuntu 14.04, Eclipse Mars). The answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/70665/145754) has a list of all the files that belong to the default theme, in addition to the `gtk-main.css` mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

The `export SWT_GTK3=0` trick did not work for me.

However, the answer listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/70665/145754) worked after trying several other solutions (Eclipse Mars 4.5.2, Ubuntu 14.04.3). I did have to edit one additional file though (`gtk-main.css`). So edit these files:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

is a viable, albeit suboptimal, workaround in **Ubuntu 16.10** and **Eclipse 4.6.1** when the desktop appearance uses the **BlueMenta** themes, with no additional tweaks required.

Tweaking the gtk-3.0 css files didn't work for me.

Other users have had better luck with the scripts [in this project](https://github.com/KiranMohan/eclipse-gtk3-ubuntu)