# Debian XFCE black background in eclipse variable hover

Tags: c++, eclipse, colors, debian, xfce

I have a problem regarding colors in eclipse. I wasnt able to set it in any way (eclipse settings and also tried gnome-color-tools). It is shown on below screen:

[image]

When I hover on an item in debug perspective while debuging, a tooltip shows. The tooltip background is black, text is white and the current item background is gray... Because of that it is not possible to see what is inder current item. How can any of those colors be changed? I would really apreciate all help and I cannot get over it for a longer while now. I am suing Debian 8.2 XFCE

Comment: I have a similar problem. Tooltip windows are showing up black even when editing java. I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5 on CentOS 7 with gnome2. I have noticed the following error when starting eclipse. **swt-tree-arrow-mode and swt-tree-arrow-color are not supported on this platform**. I'm not sure why that would be though

Answer (score 0):

found this answer on a similar question which may or may not solve your problem:

[Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers tooltip color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081589/eclipse-java-ee-ide-for-web-developers-tooltip-color)

Comment: When I do export SWT_GTK3=0 the background is still black in eclipse. When I add this to etc/profile, i think it doesnt work as after restart when I echo $SWT_GTK3 i get no output...